# PHP mysql select data multiple tables on same page

Tags: php, mysql

There are two mysql tables like this:

### table 1

> --id-----config_name
> --1-----OS
> --2-----Control Panel
> --3-----Bandwidth

### table 2

> id --    config_id---    config_Option_name ---   Price
> 1--------1-------------Windows 2008--------20.00
> 2--------1-------------CentOs 5----------------0.00
> 3--------2-------------whm/cPanel-----------30.00
> 4--------2-------------Plesk-------------------50.00

---

Now I want to show them like this:

> **OS**
> Windows 2008 = 20.00
> CentOs 5 = 00.00
> **Control Panel**
> whm/cPanel= 30.00
> Plesk = 50.00

Please help me to do that.

Comment: `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.config_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select config_name, config_Option_name, price 

from table1 
inner join table2 on (table1.id=table2.config_id)
```

Comment: not showing what i want its showing like that OS = Windows 2008 = 20.00<br>
OS =  CentOs 5 = 00.00<br>
Control Panel = whm/cPanel= 30.00<br>
Control Panel = Plesk = 50.00<br>

Answer (score 0):

To get you an idea:

```
public $dbserver = '';
public $dbusername = '';
public $dbpassword = '';
public $dbname = '';

function openDb() {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("error, please try again");
    }
    return $db;
}

function getRecords() {
    $query = "select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.config_id";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
}

$getAllRows = getRecords();

foreach ($getAllRows as $counter => $row) {
  //this is where you format and output stuff
  echo $row[0] . " and " . $row[1] . " and so on<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the thing what i was searching for

> $search = "SELECT a,b FROM DB WHERE x LIKE '$var' LIMIT 0 , 30";
>   $result = mysql_query($search, $connection);
>   if($result){
>       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>           echo $row["a"]." ".$row["b"]." ";
>           $search2 = "SELECT a,b FROM DB WHERE x = '".$row['a']."' LIMIT 0 , 100";
>           $result2 = mysql_query($search2, $connection);
>           if($result2){
>               while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
>                   echo $row2["a"]." ".$row2["b"]." ";
>               }
>           } else {
>               echo "Subject search failed.";
>               echo mysql_error();
>           }
>       }
>   } else {
>       echo "Subject search failed. ";
>       echo mysql_error();
>   }